# What is the exact meaning of "int const* " in C?

Tags: c

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [const int = int const ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3247285/const-int-int-const)
>   [Const in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/162480/const-in-c)

hi,

I would like to know the exact meaning of "int const* " in C ,And also a small comparison between "const int*"  and "int const*" in an embedded programming system.

__kanu

Comment: `int const*` and `const int*` are exactly the same.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> What is the exact meaning of “int const* ” in C?

It means a pointer to a constant integer. In other words, the pointer is not constant, but the value it points to is.

> And also a small comparison between "const int*" and "int const*"

There is no difference.

A similar construct is `int * const`. Here there *is* a difference. This time the pointer is constant but the value it points to is not.

Comment: +1 but I would phrase that a little bit differently: "pointer to a memory region with constant integers"

Comment: "A similar construct is int * const. Here the pointer is constant but the value it points to is not." what is the exact application/meaning of this usage?

Comment: See at below link. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/219914/what-use-are-const-pointers-as-opposed-to-pointers-to-const-objects