# Declaring function arguments as const in C

Tags: c, constants

What is the use of declaring arguments of a function in C as const? Does it have an impact on performance?

e.g. why would you prefer f1 to f2? Or f2 to f1?

```
void f1(const char* arg) {
/* some code */
}

void f2(char* arg) {
/* some code */
}
```

Comment: Well... Pointers passed as arguments can be modified in the function. So if they are defined as `const`, then they will always point to the same address...
Another reference: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12291607/passing-arguments-to-functions-with-const-parameters-is-it-faster

Comment: To indicate that it won't be modified, have a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9419051/declaring-a-pointer-to-const-or-a-const-pointer-to-const-as-a-formal-parameter

Comment: @PhoenixBlue of course it is wrong.

Comment: I would prefer `void f1(const char const * arg)` if `f1()` is guaranteed not to change the input `arg` or its contents

Comment: @PhoenixBlue Please look at the position of `const`. It does not affect the pointer.

Comment: @Mawg I think you meant `void f1(const char * const arg)`.

Comment: @Mawg you probably mean `void f1(const char * const arg)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`const char* arg` means that `arg` is a pointer to a constant `char`. If you try to change the data that `arg` points to, you will get an error saying something like: `error: assignment of read-only location ‘*arg’`. However, you can change the address contained in `arg`.

Whereas, by dropping the `const` keyword, you state that the data which `arg` points to *can* be changed.

Your preference should be based on your needs. Have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21476869/constant-pointer-vs-pointer-to-constant) for more information.

In response to your comment: `char * const arg` means means that `arg` is a constant (pause a second) pointer to a `char`. So, you can't change the address contained in `arg` and you *can* change the data residing at that address.

Comment: thx, so, does char * const arg, means I can change the data and not the address the pointer has?

Comment: @FakherMokadem Have updated my answer to include `char * const arg`.

Answer (score 3):

in `void f1(const char *arg)` the argument `arg` itself is not `const` qualified, it is defined as a pointer to an array of `char` that the function should not modify. This is very useful for the reader to understand at first glance that the function `f1` does not modify the string it receives.

For example `strcpy` is declared in `<string.h>` as:

```
char *strcpy(char *dest, const char *src);
```

The array pointed to by the first argument is modified, it is the destination array, the second argument points to the source array, which is not modified.

This type of `const` qualification is viral: once you define an argument as pointing to a `const` object, you can only pass it to functions that have similarly `const` qualified arguments.

Regarding the impact on performance, there is no downside. Some compilers might even benefit from this qualifications and generate better code.

So in your example, if `f1` does not modify the array pointed to by `arg`, unless you need to store `f1` in a function pointer of type `void (*)(char*)` and cannot change this type, I strongly advise to use:

```
void f1(const char *arg);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
void foo(const char *arg)
```

declares the pointer to the const char. You cant change the referenced object, but you can change the pointer

```
void foo(char * const arg)
```

declares the const pointer to the char. You cant change the the pointer, but you can change the referenced object

```
void foo(const char * const arg)
```

declares the const pointer to the const char. You cant change the the pointer and the referenced object

declaring parameters allows many compile time optimizations and may have a significant impact on the performance of the generated code.

It is considered a very good practice to use `const` for the parameters and variables which should not change. Is is called the *"const correctness"*

Futher reading: `restrict` keyword.

Comment: I would not overstate possible performance improvements, which are limited. Const correctness is more about improving code quality and reducing programmer errors.

Comment: @user694733 And what did I write in my answer? Do you see any downsides of the correct use of `const`?

Comment: No downsides. I just think that *"significant impact on the performance of the generated code."* is a bit much.

Comment: @user694733 if you consider the trivial examples yes. Not trivial ones - yes it may have.

Comment: @user if you quote me do it properly and do not change the sense of the sentence:  `and may have a significant impact`  is not the same as 'have a significant impact'

Answer (score 1):

You prefer

```
void f1(const char* arg)
```

If you don't want to modify the object pointed by arg through arg.
But you can modify the arg itself.

You prefer

```
void f2(char* arg)
```

If you want to modify the object pointed by arg through arg.

Comment: I would prefer `void f1(const char const * arg)` if `f1()` is guaranteed not to change the input `arg` or its contents

Comment: @Mawg: no, your prototype is redundant, you mean `void f1(const char * const arg)` to specify that `f1` will not change the value of the argument itself. Such `const` qualification is useless and obscures the code.